# Warning: use of operator '<' has no effect?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am new to erlang and am trying to implement a simple function as follows:

```
% * ChatServers is a dictionary of usernames with tuples of the form:
%   {server, Pid, Reference,LoggedInUsers}
get_chat_server([], _) ->        
    undefined;

get_chat_server([Key|_], ChatServers) ->
    {server, Pid, Reference,LoggedInUsers} = dict:fetch(Key,ChatServers),
    LoggedInUsers < 100,
    {server, Pid, Reference,LoggedInUsers};

get_chat_server([_|T], ChatServers) ->        
    get_chat_server(T, ChatServers).
```

Basically what I am trying to do is find the first tuple of my dictionary whose LoggedInUsers number is less than 100.

However, once I compile my code, I get the following 2 warnings:

> main_server_distributed.erl:63: Warning: use of operator '<' has no
>   effect main_server_distributed.erl:66: Warning: this clause cannot
>   match because a previous clause at line 61 always matches

**I have some experience with prolog and as far as I recall this is a valid use of pattern matching and recursion. Could you please point out what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The body of a clause (everything to the right of the `->`) is not a list of conditions to fulfil, but simply a comma-separated list of expressions to evaluate. All resulting values except from that of the last expression will be discarded. Hence, the boolean value of your `<` comparison is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```
   get_chat_server([], _) ->        
       undefined;

   get_chat_server([Key|T], ChatServers) ->
       {server, Pid, Reference,LoggedInUsers} = dict:fetch(Key,ChatServers),
       if
          LoggedInUsers < 100 -> 
              {server, Pid, Reference,LoggedInUsers};
          true -> 
              get_chat_server(T, ChatServers)
       end.
```

Or this

```
   get_chat_server([], _) ->        
       undefined;

   get_chat_server([Key|T], ChatServers) ->
       Result = dict:fetch(Key,ChatServers),
       case Result of
          {_, _, _, LoggedInUsers} when LoggedInUsers < 100 ->
             Result;
          _ -> 
             get_chat_server(T, ChatServers)
       end.
```

Answer (score 0):

> main_server_distributed.erl:66: Warning: this clause cannot match
>   because a previous clause at line 61 always matches

You've essentially written:

```
get_chat_server(NonEmptyList, ChatServers) ->
    {server, Pid, Reference,LoggedInUsers} = dict:fetch(Key,ChatServers),
    LoggedInUsers < 100,
    {server, Pid, Reference,LoggedInUsers};

get_chat_server(NonEmptyList, ChatServers) ->        
    get_chat_server(T, ChatServers).
```

Therefore, the first clause will always match anything that the second clause would have matched.  More specifically, in the pattern:

```
[Key|_]
```

`Key` will match anything and `_` will match anything.  Likewise, in the pattern:

```
[_|T]
```

`_` will match anything, and `T` will match anything.

Riffing off @dsmith's answer:

```
-module(my).
-export([get_chat_server/3, get_chat_server_test/0]).

get_chat_server(_MaxLoggedIn, []=_Keys, _ChatServers) ->        
    none;
get_chat_server(MaxLoggedIn, [Key|Keys], ChatServers) ->
    get_chat_server(MaxLoggedIn, Keys, ChatServers, dict:fetch(Key, ChatServers) ).

get_chat_server(MaxLoggedIn, _, _, {_,_,_,LoggedInUsers}=ChatServer) when LoggedInUsers < MaxLoggedIn ->
    ChatServer;
get_chat_server(MaxLoggedIn, [Key|Keys], ChatServers, _ChatServer) ->
    get_chat_server(MaxLoggedIn, Keys, ChatServers, dict:fetch(Key, ChatServers) ).

%---------

get_chat_server_test() ->
    Keys = [a, c],
    ChatServers = [
         {a, {server, a, a_, 200}},
         {b, {server, b, b_, 100}},
         {c, {server, c, c_, 30}}
    ],  
    ChatServerDict = dict:from_list(ChatServers),

    none = get_chat_server(10, [], ChatServerDict),
    {server, c, c_, 30} = get_chat_server(50, Keys, ChatServerDict),
    {server, c, c_, 30} = get_chat_server(150, Keys, ChatServerDict),
    PossibleResults = sets:from_list([{server,a,a_, 200},{server,c,c_,30}]),
    true = sets:is_element(
             get_chat_server(250, Keys, ChatServerDict),
             PossibleResults
           ),
    all_tests_passed.
```

You can also use higher order functions, i.e. [dict:fold()](http://erldocs.com/current/stdlib/dict.html?i=0&search=dict:fold#fold/3), to get a list of all the ChatServers that meet your requirements:

```
max_fun(Max, Keys) ->
    fun(Key, {_,_,_,LoggedInUsers}=Server, Acc) ->
            case lists:member(Key, Keys) andalso LoggedInUsers<Max of
                true -> [Server | Acc];
                false -> Acc
            end
    end.
```

In the shell:

```
44>     ChatServers = [
44>          {a, {server, a, a_, 200}},
44>          {b, {server, b, b_, 100}},
44>          {c, {server, c, c_, 30}}
44>     ].
[{a,{server,a,a_,200}},
 {b,{server,b,b_,100}},
 {c,{server,c,c_,30}}]

45> ChatServerDict = dict:from_list(ChatServers).
{dict,3,16,16,8,80,48,
      {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
      {{[],
        [[a|{server,a,a_,200}]],
        [[b|{server,b,b_,100}]],
        [[c|{server,c,c_,30}]],
        [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}}

46> Keys = [a,c].
[a,c]

47> MaxLoggedIn = 150.
150

50> F = my:max_fun(MaxLoggedIn, Keys).
#Fun<fl.0.128553666>

51> dict:fold(F, [], ChatServerDict).
[{server,c,c_,30}]
```